# Node.js: url route with the CNAME record

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I want to map `example.org` and `cname.example.org` to two different node.js app.
But use no http web server such as nginx.

And the web framework is `express`.

So is there are any middleware in express or node.js to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express uses connect so you can do this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.vhost('example.org', require('./exampleApp/')));
app.use(express.vhost('cname.example.org', require('./cnameExampleApp/')));

app.listen(80);
```

There is also an example on github:
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/vhost

And here the reference for connect.vhost:
http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html

**Edit:** In recent express versions, most middlewares like vhost are not included, so you will have to install them manually.

First, run:

```
$ npm install --save vhost
```

Updated code snippet:

```
const express = require("express");
const vhost = require("vhost");

const app = express();

app.use(vhost("example.org", require("./exampleApp/")));
app.use(vhost("cname.example.org", require("./cnameExampleApp/")));

app.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a proxy like nginx in anyway if your 2 node apps are hosted on the same host.

```
var request = require('request');    

var proxy = require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {    

    // distribute by request header 'host'
    var targetHost = req.headers.host;
    if (targetHost === 'example.org') {
      req.pipe(request('http://your-node-app1' + req.url)).pipe(res);
    } else if (targetHost === 'cname.example.org') {
      req.pipe(request('http://your-node-app2' + req.url)).pipe(res);
    } else { // not found or host is invalid
      res.statusCode = 404;
      res.end('host is not found!');
    }
});

proxy.listen(80); // assume it listens to port 80
```